# How to use get_terms() returning only the terms that have posts with a certain custom field value

Tags: terms, meta-value

I use get_terms() to build filter buttons to enable filtering a list of events (custom post_type).

`$terms = get_terms( 'kategorien', ['orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => 1 ]);`

Now we want to show only the terms of posts having a certain meta_value.
Anybody knows how to achive this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'kategorien',
  'orderby' => 'slug',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'hide_empty' => true,
  'meta_key' => 'YOUR_KEY_VALUE',
  'meta_value' => true
);

$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you – unfortunately this doesn't work. Your solution is targeting the term meta. I'm looking for post meta...

Answer (score 0):

ok this is how I solved it:

```
    //1. Get all events with meta field 

        $args = [
          'post_type' => "events",
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'meta_query' => [
            [
             'key'       => 'event_archive',
             'value'     => "true",
             'compare'   => '!='
            ]
           ],
          'fields'        => 'ids',       
        ];
                
        $myEvents = new WP_Query( $args );
      
 //2. Get all terms including only posts from first query 
             
        $args = [
            'taxonomy'   => 'kategorien',
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'orderby' => 'slug',
           'object_ids' => $myEvents->posts, 
        ];
                    
        $myTerms = get_terms( $args);
```